# Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac creating invalid imports on new Objective-C classes via XCode

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've been having some issues with the ports Visual Studio makes when creating the source code files for Xcode.

When starting a new project through Visual Studio, then opening the `Main.storyboard` on Xcode, adding the necessary views and associating them to custom classes and returning to Visual Studio to create the `*.cs` files so I can add the functionality, when returning to the Xcode -- the program is restarted after Visual Studio compiles all the required files -- I'm required to build the app within Xcode so I can have access to the `*.m` and `*.h` source files, and often I'm prompt with `Lexical or Preprocessor Issue` where the `*.h` files may, or may not, contain an invalid import in the form of `#import <[nameOfProject]/[nameOfProject].h>` -- which I believe it does not exist --, and may, or may not, have the `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` missing.

Is there anything I can do to avoid this import from being added?

As of now, my method is to check every `*.h` source file belonging to my code and removing the invalid `#import` and checking if the `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` is present.

---

#### Versions

- Xcode 9.0 9A235
- Visual Studio Community for Mac 7.1.5 build 2

Comment: Are you adding custom `.m`/`.h` to the temp xcodeproj project that Visual Studio creates so you can define outlets and actions within a Storyboard?

Comment: No. I haven't mess with anything inside the `bin` or `obj` folders, although I've discarded those folders when copying the project to the current location.

Comment: `I'm required to build the app within Xcode so I can have access to the *.m and *.h source file` : I guess I'm confused by that statement then....?

Comment: What I meant there was that sometimes, in Xcode, when I try to add a button, for instance, to the `*.h` source file, the file is missing / not recognized ( even if I try to set it manually within Xcode ). In those cases I need to build the app in Xcode in order to have access to those files and add the views.